# C++11 Simplest way to store multiple data types for value(int and string) in map<key, value>?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to have a map that uses

- string for key
- int OR string for value

like this:

```
std::map<std::string, SOME TYPE> myMap;
myMap["first_key"]  = 10;
myMap["second_key"] = "stringValue";
```

What is the **SIMPLEST** way to do such thing?

added) I am looking for solution that works in c++11

Comment: `std::variant<int, std::string>` in c++17, you may look at boost prior to this.

Comment: C++ is strongly typed. In almost every case, if you're trying to use varying types in a container you're doing complicated reads and writes to the container that could be simplified by separating into multiple containers and using templatized read write methods.

Comment: @Jarod42 Is there similar thing in c++11?

Comment: "You may look at boost prior to this"

Comment: Can the type of `value` be determined only looking at the `key`? E.g. `myMap["program_path"]` => string, `myMap["height_mm"]` => integer. If this is the case you may always use a string and convert to integer when required.

Comment: @manlio Is that efficient though? I have 10 ints and 5 strings to store as values.

Comment: It depends on the usage pattern: the string to int conversion require some time but if `myMap` is a (sort of) "configuration file" then it isn't a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In c++17, you may use `std::variant<int, std::string>`, prior to this, you may use the one from `boost`:

```
using IntOrString = std::variant<int, std::string>;
std::map<std::string, IntOrString> myMap;
myMap["first_key"]  = 10;
myMap["second_key"] = "stringValue";
```

Comment: Wow..! can we have more than two typename inside `variant`?

Comment: Any numbers of type.